# C#, Socket.Bind when using the 0 as port

Tags: c#, .net, port, bind

In MSDN, there is a sentence,

"If you do not care which local port is used, you can create an IPEndPoint using 0 for the port number. In this case, the service provider will assign an available port number between 1024 and 5000"

My confusion is: 
When the Client want to connect to server,

Does the client still need to know which port the server is listening?

Or the Client just connect to the 0 port.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The client still needs to know which port the server was actually bound to, and connect to that.

An example of this in action is in the `FTP` protocol. Normally when using active mode, the server uses one (known) port for commands, and binds an extra dynamic port for data transfer. When a data transfer starts, the server *sends the actual port in a message to the client over the command channel*, and the client then connects to the (psudo-random) data port it just got informed about to get the actual file data.

Answer (score 0):

when you connect to  server ,you must know  ip+port decide your application to link which process on the remoting server.

socket  connect  like that

your  :IP                                                                           server:Ip
                < =============================================================>
your :  port                                                                      server:port

so  in client.  you do not care which local port.  when you connect to the server ,server had know the port .